# Paypal monthly recurring

Tags: paypal, recurring-events, donations

I need an auto monthly recurring tick yes on PayPal donation. Please help me with this.

[Check out this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvIji.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can check an option to make monthly recurring when setting up the donate button on [developer.paypal.com/donate/buttons](https://developer.paypal.com/donate/buttons), check the image below.

[image: adding monthly recurring option]

Answer (score 0):

For a monthly recurring PayPal payment that is always recurring, you can create a Subscribe button -- and change its image to be "Donate" or any other image you wish.

---

With a normal donate flow, if you want the donations to be monthly, ask your donors to check the box during checkout. The box is there for them to make the decision.